# Clicking on push notification from wearable opens app but clicking on notification from phone does nothing.

Tags: android, notifications

This is my first time implementing a push notification and from what I understand if I am using NotificationCompat then it is supposed to just work with phone and wearables. So why will clicking on my phone notification not open my app but it works on wearable.

BTW My push notification code is all in OnCreate.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_ID);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mommy-info.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //notification code

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                R.mipmap.baby, getString(R.string.app_name), pendingIntent).build();


        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentText("Come check out some of our new posts.")
                .setContentTitle("It's been awhile")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.baby)
                .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action))
                .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(001, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```